# Можно ли как то определить свайп по экрану?

Tags: android, swipe

Можно ли как то определить свайп по элементу?

Answer (score 4):

Нужно имплементировать интерфейс `OnGestureListener`

```
public class Adds extends Activity implements OnGestureListener
```

см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617377/onswipeint-direction-not-working и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures